# Clicking a Spinner Menu Item does not bring up the spinner list

Tags: android, menu, spinner, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a menu item with a spinner layout and its appearing properly in my action bar's menu. However, when I click on the spinner, nothing is happening. I have log messages in the onOptionsItemSelected and I'm not seeing any message in logcat. Here are snippets of my code:

Menu layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/spinner_layout"  />
</menu>
```

Spinner Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_drawable">
</Spinner>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_1).getActionView();

    MySpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(this);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerAdapter);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    log.error("ON OPTIONS ITEM SELECTED FOR ITEM: " + item.getItemId());

    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.menu_item_1:
            log.error("ON OPTIONS ITEM SELECTED - SPINNER MENU ITEM SELECTED");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MySpinnerAdapter.java

@Singleton
public class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter, OnItemSelectedListener{

```
@Inject
public TopbarErrorSpinnerAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.my_spinner_item);
    this.values = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<MySpinnerRowEntry>());
    this.context = context;
    this.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_item);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values.size();
}

@Override
public MySpinnerRowEntry getItem(int position) {
    return values.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row = View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_spinner_item, null);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner_item_icon);

    return image;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int rowPosition = position;

    View row = View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_spinner_item, null);

    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner_item_title);
    title.setText(values.get(position).getTitle());

    TextView message = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner_item_message);
    message.setText(values.get(position).getMessage());

    row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mySpinnerAdapterlistener.mySpinnerItemSelected(values.get(rowPosition).getType());
        }
    });

    return row;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
    (activity).onOptionsItemSelected((MenuItem) activity.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_1));
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

I'm also unsure how to trigger the Spinner if the menu item selected is the spinner. I had this same spinner working in a previous activity that didn't include an ActionBar. Due to changes in my application after upgrading to SDK 14, I know have to add the spinner to the Menu of the ActionBar.

Thank you all for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve my problem using the ActionProvider. I had to define an ActionProvider for the menu item in the xml code, and implement the provider. in the OnCreateActionView, this is where I instantiate the spinner adapter and assigned it to the spinner. 
One thing to point out is that the OnCreateActionView() method has been deprecated and another implementation OnCreateActionView(MenuItem menuItem) is made available. However, if you want your code to work on something like API 14 and API 16, you will have to implement both methods (identically).
Hope this helps others...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the spinner is consuming the touch event. In `MySpinnerAdapter#onItemSelected`, you probably have to programmatically select the menu item. Call `myActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(R.id.menu_item_1)` by hand.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. However, that doesn't seem to be the case. The spinner adapter is not receiving the event. Any other ideas?

Comment: I misunderstood. So neither of `onOptionsItemSelected` / `onItemSelected` is called? Does the spinner change to the newly selected item? It might also be helpful if you post the `MySpinnerAdapter` code.